# Django and APScheduler on the same Postgres failed to run test

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In my project code. I have `Django 1.11` and `APScheduler 3.3.1` running with `Postgres 9.6`

The problem is during the full testcaes. `APScheduler` hits database `Postgres` before Django finish the migrations.

On my OSX Laptop does not has that problem.

Is there any technique I can avoid this problem?

### Update

`models.py`

```
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

schd_inst = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores={
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(
        url=settings.DATABASE_URL,
        tablename='apscheduler_jobs'
    )
})

try:
     schd_inst.start()
 except SchedulerAlreadyRunningError:
     logger.info(str(SchedulerAlreadyRunningError))

class MailAPIScheduler(DirtyFieldsMixin, AbstractSoftModelController):
    dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    api_url = models.URLField()
    schedule_time = JSONField(default={'hour': 0, 'minute': 0})  # 24hr e.g. {'hour': 13, 'minute': 3}
    parameters = JSONField()  # {'key': 'api-key', 'value': '123'}
    summary_email_receivers = ArrayField(
        models.EmailField(blank=True),
        blank=True
    )
    schd_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)  # uuid gen at python code not database level
```

`settings.py`

```
LOCAL_APPS = [
    ...,
    'myapp',
    ...
]
```

**Error:**

```
python manage.py test
Scheduler DB: postgres://postgres:qwerty@postgres:5432/eneos_pos
Hey, I'm Local!
Scheduler DB: postgres://postgres:qwerty@postgres:5432/eneos_pos
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "eneos_pos" does not exist
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  database "eneos_pos" does not exist
FAILEDBuild failed !!!.
```

Comment: This is too less context to even understand your question. Show some code. How are you testing ? does it fail with any error?

Comment: I could not get much from question ifself but I think re-sequencing your application (may be test framework startup) should be good idea?
Migrations should be first thing you should do before doing anything else with DB.